# Send data to Arduino via Express without request

Tags: javascript, express, arduino

I have an Express server running and Arduinos currently make POST requests to it. The server then does some other processing.

I'm trying to make Express to send an event (data) to the Arduino and then have the Arduino generate an interrupt when it receives the data.

However, I'd like Express to send data to the Arduino without the Arduino sending an HTTP request to the server in the first place.

I could periodically poll the server but I don't expect events to happen often and I think polling the server every second or so to see if new data is available is wasteful.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).send({ message: "Success!" });
});

//Invalid code but lets say the Arduino was on IP 192.168.0.223 
//and we wanted to push data to it

app.sendData("192.168.0.233", {temperature: 20.0});
```

To clarify, above is part of my code. If I make a request *from* the Arduino to Express route '/' then I can send a *response* with data from the server to the Arduino.

However, if the Arduino never made a request in the first place, how can I send (or push) data to it?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 177);


EthernetServer server(80);

void setup() {

  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial.println("Ethernet WebServer Example");

  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  // Check for Ethernet hardware present
  if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
    while (true) {
      delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
    }
  }
  if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
  }

  // start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop() {
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("new client");
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) { <-- this is blocking code 
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        Serial.write(c);
        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
          // send a standard http response header
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
          client.println("Refresh: 5");  // refresh the page automatically every 5 sec
          client.println();
          client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
          client.println("<html>");
          // output the value of each analog input pin
          for (int analogChannel = 0; analogChannel < 6; analogChannel++) {
            int sensorReading = analogRead(analogChannel);
            client.print("analog input ");
            client.print(analogChannel);
            client.print(" is ");
            client.print(sensorReading);
            client.println("<br />");
          }
          client.println("</html>");
          break;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        } else if (c != '\r') {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disconnected");
  }
}
```

The above [snippet](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LibraryExamples/WebServer) sets up a server on the Arduino but it still has to actively listen for connections and then check to see if the client is connected and then read in the data. If this is the way it *has* to be done then I'll rethink my approach.

I wanted the server to simply send data to an IP and the Arduino will generate an [interrupt](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=704486.0) that I can service. Sort of how UART works? There's no initial request data just comes along and generates an interrupt that you can handle.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for help with.  The Express server either responds to an incoming request or you set a timer for it to make a request to your Arduino on some schedule.  Just because you're polling, doesn't mean you have to poll every second.  You can poll every 5 minutes if you want.  If your Arduino supports it, you could also be continuously connected with the Express server via a webSocket or socket.io connection.

Comment: @jfriend00 I know and I appreciate you still helping. I know Express can _respond_ to a request. But I want Express to just send data without serving a request. Exactly like your suggestion "set a timer for it to make a request to your Arduino on some schedule". But I don't know how to send a request, only how to _respond_ to one

Comment: @jfriend00 I've added a code snippet for clarification

Comment: For someone to send data directly to the arduino, it must have a server that is listening on some port using some protocol.  Does it have an http server?  Or some other type of server?  On what port?

Comment: @jfriend00 no there's no server on the Arduino. Is there any way I can have a server listen and respond to incoming data , on the Arduino, without it being blocking? Like specifying a callback when it detects incoming data? I've updated my question

Comment: I don't know the Arduino programming environment, but yes there are ways to listen for incoming connections without blocking in many environments.  If this is now an Arduino programming question, I'll have to bow out and wait for someone else to come by the help.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jfriend00 for pointing me in the direction of websockets and this article for [general guidance](https://salfade.com/tutorials/realtime-communication-with-nodemcu-with-socketio)

I decided to use [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) for the server:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 3005 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  
  setInterval(() => {
    ws.send(`${new Date()}`);
  }, 1000);
});
```

And on the Arduino the [ATmega branch of the WebSockets library](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets/tree/ATmega)

```
#define MONITOR_SPEED               921600

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <WebSocketsClient.h>

WebSocketsClient webSocket;

//MAC address for arduino- these can be manually assigned 
//but cannot conflict with any other address on the same network
byte mac[] = {0xAE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};

// Set the static IP address to use if the DHCP fails to assign
static IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 177);
static IPAddress myDns(192, 168, 0, 1);
static EthernetClient client;


void webSocketEvent(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {

    switch(type) {
        case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
            Serial.println("[WSc] Disconnected!\n");
            break;
        case WStype_CONNECTED:
            {
                Serial.print("[WSc] Connected to url: ");
                Serial.println((char *)payload);
                // send message to server when Connected
                webSocket.sendTXT("Connected");
                
            }
            break;
        case WStype_TEXT:
            Serial.print("[WSc] get text: ");
            Serial.println((char *)payload);
            // send message to server
            // webSocket.sendTXT("message here");
            break;
        case WStype_BIN:
            Serial.print("[WSc] get binary length: ");
            Serial.println(length);
           // hexdump(payload, length);

            // send data to server
            // webSocket.sendBIN(payload, length);
            break;
    }

}


void setup()
{

    // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
    Serial.begin(MONITOR_SPEED);  //921600
    while (!Serial)
    {
        ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
    }

    // start the Ethernet connection:
    Serial.println("Initialize Ethernet with DHCP:");
    if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0)
    {

        Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
        
        // Check for Ethernet hardware present
        if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware)
        {
            Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.");
            Serial.println("Program will continue to run without shield but will not report to web server");
        }

        if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF)
        {
            Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
        }

        // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
        Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, myDns);
    }

    byte macBuffer[6];              // create a buffer to hold the MAC address
    Ethernet.MACAddress(macBuffer); // fill the buffer
    Serial.print(" MAC address : ");
    for (byte octet = 0; octet < 6; octet++)
    {
        Serial.print(macBuffer[octet], HEX);
        if (octet < 5)
        {
            Serial.print(':');
        }
    }
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("  DHCP assigned IP : ");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

    webSocket.begin("192.168.0.189", 3005);
    webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
    
}



void loop()
{
   webSocket.loop();
   Ethernet.maintain();
   if (!client.connected()) {
     client.stop();
   }
  
}
```

This should print the current date and time on your serial monitor:

```
[WSc] get text: Fri Mar 19 2021 10:13:12 GMT-0400 (Atlantic Standard Time)
[WSc] get text: Fri Mar 19 2021 10:13:13 GMT-0400 (Atlantic Standard Time)
[WSc] get text: Fri Mar 19 2021 10:13:14 GMT-0400 (Atlantic Standard Time)
[WSc] get text: Fri Mar 19 2021 10:13:15 GMT-0400 (Atlantic Standard Time)
[WSc] get text: Fri Mar 19 2021 10:13:16 GMT-0400 (Atlantic Standard Time)
```

And on your server:

```
received: Connected
```